# Android display array of logs in real-time

Tags: java, android, timer, timertask

I have an array of logs, of which includes a `time-stamp per log` (dealing in seconds). I would like to `update my UI (with the logs)` in a way such that it updates in `real-time`. I'm unsure how I can implement this, if it will involve a `TimerTask or using a Handler...`

The app is set up to just take `the data and update` it whenever it receives it, but I need to add in a method of starting a timer, `look at my logs` and if the timer is greater than or equal to the `logged time,` then `pass it to UI`, then most likely `remove the log`.

Comment: Where do the logs come from? Server, intern database or are are they created by the user inside the app and you want to add them in a list?

Comment: They come a log file, which lives in storage on the android. I can 'load' a log file, which involves reading the log file (ASCII text) and creating an array of log objects that live in the app during run-time.

Comment: Forgive me for being too vague, I can easily update the UI using the log data with no issue. Though, at this moment, this isn't done based on time, it's just iterating through the array and updating the UI with each individual element. I would like to do this, but introduce a timer element such that if there is a 2 second gap in between one log and the next, I would like to reflect that in the UI.

Comment: I dont exactly understand how you want to handle this. I will post you a piece of code of a handler that you can try to implement the way you need it

Comment: final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        //Do something after 100ms
        Toast.makeText(c, "check", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
        handler.postDelayed(this, 2000);
      }
    }, 1500);